# using iframe calling my aspx page to html page ,how to do it?

Tags: asp.net, html

I having an error that when I give the `iframe` code in html

```
<iframe  runat="server" src="~/Contactus.aspx" style="width: 840px; height: 233px"></iframe>
```

the `src` path was given properly. but it was showing the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /contact us/~/Contactus.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error that was returned: `Requested URL: /contact us/~/Contactus.aspx`

Try modifying the code to be like this:

```
<iframe  runat="server" src="Contactus.aspx" style="width: 840px; height: 233px"></iframe>
```