# How to execute aspx file within html using iframe

Tags: html, asp.net

i am having a contact.html page which is hosted in IIS .Now i need to refer aspx page using iframe which performs some process.is there any possibility to call aspx page if so how can i link in IIS ?

How to build aspx page to link with html page?

if i link using iframe the error displays as below:

`Server Error in '/' Application.`

Runtime Error

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: one link on stackexchange it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001021/using-iframe-calling-my-aspx-page-to-html-page-how-to-do-it

Comment: you need to check the path, it seems incorrect path to aspx.

Comment: i verified the path.it doesn't get executed.i need to know how server side coding will get executed if i link aspx page with iframe in html?